# CNC Y-axis stepper moving forward but not in opposite direction

Tags: arduino-motor-shield

I'm building an CNC mill with an Arduino UNO with a CNC Shield V3. But I have a problem with the Y motor direction. It only moves in one way while the X motor is moving both ways. When I just installed everything it worked, but after a view tries it doesn't anymore. I viewed multiple topics on this problem but nothing is working.

- I tried to switch the stepper drives but that didn't make a difference.
- Switched the stepper motors and then the x motor moved in one way so it isn't the stepper motor.
- Tried cloning the Y controller to the 4th connection. Also didn't work.
- Tried multiple GRBL HEX files, all the same.
- I also tried multiple gcode senders but is just doesn't make a difference.

Is there anything else that I can try to help this problem? Or shall I order an new shield to test if this shield is broken.

Comment: So, what code is running on the Uno? How exactly is it conected to a motor? Link to the attached CNC shield and it's pinout? Pictures of the setup maybe?

Comment: Have you blown one of your drivers? Try swapping them around.

Comment: if one of the motor windings was not driven,  then the motor would fail to turn in either direction ... either the motor driver has a bad *direction* pin (if there is one), or the problem is caused by software

Comment: The code is running on the Uno is GRBL and the driver board is A4988, on the cnc shield 3 and i was even trying to interchange the driver and the motor no improvement

Comment: Check the DIR signal to the Y controller.